# Returning a Table from an Oracle function, defined within an anonymous block

Tags: sql, oracle, function, anonymous

I've got a DECLARE block like this

```
DECLARE
  TYPE WordList IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50);

  FUNCTION getWordList
    RETURN WordList
  IS
    words WordList := WordList();  
  BEGIN
    words.EXTEND;
    words(1) := 'aardvark';
    RETURN words;
  END;

BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM TABLE(getWordList);

END;
/
```

When I try to run this from sqlplus I get this...

```
ERROR at line 15:
ORA-06550: line 15, column 23:
PLS-00231: function 'GETWORDLIST' may not be used in SQL
ORA-06550: line 15, column 23:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "GETWORDLIST": invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 15, column 3:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

It seems that If I were to define the function outside the anonymous block then it would work ok, but I'm trying to avoid that since I want to run some functions against the live database, and I'd prefer not to be creating and dropping functions on live as the script runs. If I only define things in anonymous functions then I don't have any clean up to do.

What I'm trying to do is write a function which will return a list of results (in whatever form, collection, cursor, I'm not fussy) which I can then pass into another function for further processing. The functions may be arbitrarily complex, and I will want to reuse them in the future, hence writing functions rather than just writing everything in a single SQL statement.

I'm new to Oracle, so trying to find idioms and ways of working which go with the grain, rather than against it.

Answer (score 1):

The `Function` and the `Type`  has to be available in Oracle globally, to be used in `SQL` ..

Any `SELECT` would actually send the context to the SQL Engine and the query executed there. Sending the results back to the PL/SQL Engine..

For just `PL/SQL` call *Eg:* Plain logics without `SQL`s, your method will work..

So the below needs to be done..

Create the Type as SQL Object.

```
CREATE TYPE WordList IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50);
```

Declare the function

```
  CREATE FUNCTION getWordList
    RETURN WordList
  IS
    words WordList := WordList();  
  BEGIN
    words.EXTEND;
    words(1) := 'aardvark';
    RETURN words;
  END;
  /
```

Call it then

```
BEGIN
  SELECT * INTO SOMERECORD FROM TABLE(getWordList);
END;
/
```

Comment: That's what I was trying to avoid doing. It may be that it's not possible in that case, in which case I'm looking for alternative strategies to do what I want.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you're looking for. And it is not possible as SQL needs it defined globally. You may try to put all your `FUNCTION` and `TYPE` declaration in a script. And also the caller block too.. It _appears_ as a single local declaration. But Oracle 12c has brought in some nice features like this. But I am not sure though.